# Is Kalman filtering a suitable approach to predict data from a set of/or a single feature?

Tags: time-series, predictive-modeling, kalman-filter

I have multiple repeats of a time series that I would like to use to train a model to predict future repeats. The time series contains feature data (easy to measure) and target data (hard to measure). I would like to use the feature data to predict the target data. Is Kalman filtering a suitable approach for this? I would be interested in doing this using python.

Comment: Kalman filter can track non-stationary time series and estimate certain hard to observe quantities, but given the little information in the question it is hard to tell

Comment: @NikosM. I can add I am currently approaching the problem in 2 methods. 1) An LSTM using the feature data to predict the target data. 2) A regression problem.

Comment: Ok but this does not say anything about the problem itself, except that it is a time series